# Join user-defined table type param to view

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, view, temp-tables

SQL Server 2012: I have a stored procedure with a parameter of user-defined table-type.

To create its return rowset, the stored procedure selects from a view joined to the param table on a few columns none of which have indexes (which are problematic to add for other reasons).

Is it better to :

1. load the entire view into a local temp table and then select against a join of the temp table and the param table
2. directly select from the view joined to the parameter table

The view can contain up to ~1 million rows.

Is there any advantage either way? Or does SQL Server internally implement both approaches in a similar manner?

Comment: Here is what you **do not** do. You don't guess. Write it both ways and evaluate the performance by examining the execution plan. If you cannot index the source tables (nb: **tables** - a view is simply a pre-written query) and they have no useful indexes for your join, then it may not make any difference. But that is just guessing - which is something we should not do.

Answer (score 1):

I will start with creating temporary table in which to insert the user-defined table type. The defined table-type is practically a table-variable and joining table variables to other  objects is pretty slow in some cases because the SQL Engine does not good information about how many rows the table-variable has.

The second thing that can be optimize is the view. The questions here are:

1. Do you really need view? Won't be better to use a inline-table valued function also know as view with parameters? If you can pass some parameters to this function that can be use to filter the data in advanced (imagine not returning all rows but part of them) you can improve the performance as well.
2. If you really need this data in view, could be the view [indexed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15#additional-requirements)?

Comment: How is an inline table-valued function more performant than just querying the view ?   Will SQL Server cache the result rowset of a function for a each unique set of values for the input parameters ?  However in my case the in params repeat very seldom.

Comment: @BaltoStar There are various cases. Too many to describe them in a comment. In context of this question, the OP try to store the data in a temporary table which to be join. If we have a function we can store only part of the data in temporary table and reduce the volume of working data.